# How to access the preview video of a movie file with Google Drive SDK?

Tags: google-drive-api

On the Google Drive app for iOS, when I open a video file, I immediately preview the file through a low quality version of it. It's not the original file.

So do you know how to get the url of this preview video?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

Use the `embedLink` field of the file. It contains a link to a player that streams the video (YouTube, pretty much), suitable for a mobile app.

Comment: Unfortunately, the embedLink of a video is an SWF player, meaning it's not readable on iOS. Any other idea?